# How can I achieve this in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When I have a collection such as:

```
{
   "_id":"123",
   "xxx":{"yyy":1,"zzz":2}
}
```

I can use this:

```
db.collection.update({"_id":"123"},{"set":{"xxx.yyy":3}})
```

So the result is:

```
{
   "_id":"123",
   "xxx":{"yyy":3,"zzz":2}
}
```

But if I want to modify "yyy" to "kkk" ,such as:

```
{
   "_id":"123",
   "xxx":{"kkk":3,"zzz":2}
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this in mongodb? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`$rename`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/) operator to rename fields:

```
db.collection.update({"_id": "123"}, {"$rename": {"xxx.yyy": "xxx.kkk"}})
```

Comment: Thanks.I try it on my db,but it seems doesn't works.mongod --version：
db version v2.0.6, pdfile version 4.5

Comment: and when I use safe model,It return "Invalid modifier specified $rename "

Comment: sorry for my mistake.I just find that I was use remote-server totest,that db version is 1.6.3...So thanks for your answer!